# How to do a Volley PUT to a drupal table

Tags: java, android, drupal, drupal-7, android-volley

I'm attempting to do a PUT in x-www-form-urlencoded to a drupal table with Volley from my Android app. I'm try to send a 'type' and 'value', in the params and I get a 500 error.  A basic StringRequest returns 404.

Here's my latest code. I've only found one or two entries that touch on the Volley Put.  Any help would be appreciated.  Have a great day.

```
private void postTestAnswerResult(String id, String answerResult) {

    StringRequest req = null;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    final String baseURL = "http://blah.blah.com/api/answer/";
    String URL = baseURL + id;
    // Post params to be sent to the server
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    params.put("type", answerResult);



    req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, URL,

    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString());
        }
    },

    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            try {
                String responseBody = new String(
                        volleyError.networkResponse.data, "utf-8");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Handle a malformed json response
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException error) {

            }
        }
    }

    );

    requestQueue.add(req);

}
```

Comment: A 500 error means the server found an error. You find more information about the error in the server log file.

Comment: Thanks. I've heard that 500 errors are sent back a lot and browser basically ignore them.  Does the above code look correct?  Thanks.

Comment: 500 means server error.  If the server tell you there is a error, look at least in the error.log. The brwoser may ignores it because it can not do anything. But you can do something, look into the error.log !

Comment: You are not using the params variable in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still having problems with this, as @Meier points out in a comment above, you are not using the params variable, or rather you aren't using it correctly. The data doesn't get sent to the server, and the server is probably expecting the data resulting in the 500 error.

You need to override the getParams method of the StringRequest call in order to send the data. So, the following would be closer to getting the job done:

```
private void postTestAnswerResult(String id, String answerResult) {
  StringRequest req = null;
  requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

  final String baseURL = "http://blah.blah.com/api/answer/";
  String URL = baseURL + id;



  req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, URL,

    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString());
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            try {
                String responseBody = new String(
                        volleyError.networkResponse.data, "utf-8");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // Handle a malformed json response
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException error) {

            }
        }
    }
) {
  @Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams()
  { 
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); This shouldn't be here. This is a HTTP header. If you want to specify header you should also override getHeaders. 
    params.put("type", answerResult);  

    return params;
  }

};

 requestQueue.add(req);
```

Browser don't ignore 500 errors. They very often show up as ugly messages in the browser window.